# Embedding images in ItemRenderer in Flex

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, embed

If I embed some image in `DataGroup` as follows:

```
[Embed(source="/assets/someimage.png")]
private var someimageClass:Class;
```

Will the image be embedded as many times as there are items in `DataGroup`? Would it be considered a bad practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Will the image be embedded as many times as there are items in DataGroup

No, image will be embedded only once. You can access it by the name `ItemRendererName_someimageClass`. Consider your item renderer class name is `TT`:

```
    trace(getDefinitionByName("TT_someimageClass"));
    trace(ApplicationDomain.currentDomain.getDefinition("TT_someimageClass"));
```

output:

```
[class TT_someimageClass]
[class TT_someimageClass]
```

> Would it be considered a bad practice?

By AS3 code style convention (that used in may opensource projects, as3 livedocs examples and flex) the common way to embed assets is to use `public static const` for public assets and `private static const` for private assets, but it seems there isn't any difference in access performance between all these cases, check out this benchmark:

```
package
{
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.utils.getTimer;

public class astest extends Sprite
{
    public function astest()
    {
        var tt1:TT = new TT();

        var clazz:Class;
        var t:uint, i:int;

        t == getTimer();
        for(i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
            clazz = TT.someimageClass2;
        trace("static var:", (getTimer() - t), "ms");

        t == getTimer();
        for(i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
            clazz = TT.someimageClass3;
        trace("static const:", (getTimer() - t), "ms");

        t == getTimer();
        for(i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
            clazz = tt1.someimageClass;
        trace("var:", (getTimer() - t), "ms");

        t == getTimer();
        for(i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
            clazz = tt1.someimageClass1;
        trace("const:", (getTimer() - t), "ms");

        var cache:Class = tt1.someimageClass;
        t == getTimer();
        for(i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
            clazz = cache;
        trace("cache:", (getTimer() - t), "ms");

    }

}
}

package
{

public class TT
{
    [Embed(source="vogel_small.jpg")]
    public var someimageClass:Class;

    [Embed(source="vogel_small.jpg")]
    public const someimageClass1:Class;

    [Embed(source="vogel_small.jpg")]
    public static const someimageClass2:Class;

    [Embed(source="vogel_small.jpg")]
    public static var someimageClass3:Class;

    public function TT()
    {
    }
}
}
```

output:

```
static var: 85 ms
static const: 94 ms
var: 102 ms
const: 110 ms
cache: 118 ms
```

All results are in the range of 10% error, you can swap any two test and get the same time about ~100ms, so there isn't any difference for performance in a way you embed assets.

Comment: Thank you, @fsbmain! Appreciate your help!!